# keyPressed and keyReleased don't work

Tags: java, macos, swing, keyboard

I was making a simple electronic queue and ran into a difficulty.

I wanted to make admin login pop up when a certain key is pressed and the "Login" button is clicked (is there a better way to do this?), so I let the class implement KeyListener. But the `keyPressed()`, `keyTyped()` and `keyReleased()` are never called!

Here is the code:

```
package net.koya.pleasewait;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PleaseWait implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    private boolean shiftDown = false;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PleaseWait pleaseWait = new PleaseWait();

        JFrame admin = new JFrame("Queue admin");
        JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton login = new JButton("Login");

        login.setAlignmentX(0.5f);
        login.addActionListener(pleaseWait);

        loginPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(loginPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        loginPanel.add(login);

        admin.addKeyListener(pleaseWait);
        admin.setContentPane(loginPanel);
        admin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        admin.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        admin.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (shiftDown)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "Admin mode!", "Hello, World!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
            System.out.println("Shift pressed");
            shiftDown = true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
            System.out.println("Shift released");
            shiftDown = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }
}
```

By the way, I'm using `javaSE-1.8.0_101` on `macOS 10.13.3`.

Any help will be appreciated, as I have never encountered such a problem before.

Comment: Do you have any further doubts related to this question?

Comment: Not really. I think the problem is solved, everything works fine at least. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this: Your JButton `login` commands the focus of your JPanel `loginPanel`. So even if you press a key on the JPanel, the JButton takes control of the command, and because the JButton does not have a KeyListener, it does nothing.

To solve the problem, simply add `login.setFocusable(false)` like this:

```
loginPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(loginPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
loginPanel.add(login);

login.setFocusable(false);

loginPanel.addKeyListener(pleaseWait);
admin.addKeyListener(pleaseWait);
admin.setContentPane(loginPanel);
admin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
admin.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
admin.setVisible(true);
```

Now, the JButton stops commanding the attention of the KeyListener, and the JPanel is able to recognize the key-press.

Even though the JButton is not able to be focused on, it will still execute its action. So, your program will work correctly!